# VB.net sort column then sort off but retain rows position

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I can sort datagridview column by automatic sortmode. But my problem is, when i set column is automatic sort that mean The "Status" column always in sort mode and if there have any data change it will move to anythere following sort mode

[image]

[image]

I don't wanna this. I just want sort on and then off but retain the row position. I mean:

step 1: when user change status of the "Status" column, it isn't sort data

step 2: then, when user click to column header, it sort data descending

step 3: after that, when user change any status of the "Status" column, it is not sort but retain rows position in datagridview (that mean row which status is changed, doesn't move to anywhere)

is there any right way to achieve this? Thanks you for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I suggest in this situation:

1. If your grid is not already bound to a `DataTable`, do so.
2. Add an extra column to your `DataTable` with data type `Integer`.
3. Either create and bind your grid columns yourself and don't create one for that extra column or else hide that grid column after binding.
4. Sort your grid as desired.
5. Loop through the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` and set the values in the extra column sequentially.
6. Assign the name of that extra column to the `Sort` property of the `DefaultView`.

That's it.  The data is now sorted by that numeric sequence in that column so you can make whatever changes you want to the rest of the data without affecting the order.

Comment: Thanks for your idea but what if user close app and open again. Because extra column doesn't exist in database, grid view will be reseted to default (by default datagrid is sorted by hidden "ID" column which is a primarykey). Following your idea, I have some modification with it. By default, ID column is sorted, When user click to "Status" column header, "Status" column is sorted, then I loop though defaultview and get indexs from "ID" column (Primary key), arrange those of indexs and put back to "ID" column. Then, I sort ID column again.

Comment: I don't know is there any problem when i directly use "ID" column instead create a extra column

Comment: Generally speaking, once you create an ID for a record, that ID should not change.  It's up to you to determine whether changing it in this case could cause any problems but, personally, I would use different columns for identification and sorting purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, i got it, i will create a "sorted" column and use this column to sort instead directly use "ID" column :))